# Vapor deploy to Heroku with log error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET

Tags: heroku, swift4, vapor

After many research and tried, I still cannot resolved the problem. I use `Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.2` & `Vapor Framework: 2.3.0` and Swift `4.0.3`(Xcode 9.2 on macos-high-sierra) to build a simple website(without database). But after run `vapor heroku push` successful, I try goto `heroku dashboard` to open my website, but it didn't work. I try to run `heroku logs` and got the result with crashed:

```
2017-12-26T09:04:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-12-26T09:10:00.192686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2017-12-26T09:10:00.207462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-26T09:10:00.210981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-26T09:10:03.369454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `leeswift --env=production --port=19489`
2017-12-26T09:10:00.072884+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: leeswift: command not found
2017-12-26T09:10:05.460027+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: leeswift: command not found
2017-12-26T09:10:05.560609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2017-12-26T09:10:05.594754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-26T09:11:28.858638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=leeswift.herokuapp.com request_id=0eab887e-dba0-488e-b3f6-899de07898d6 fwd="118.69.108.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? And is it constant or intermittent?

Answer (score 2):

> bash: leeswift: command not found

Your heroku buildpack cannot find the produced executable for the vapor app. This is likely an issue with the name/path to the application. I haven't used heroku yet, but Swift produces it's executbles in `.build/release/<my-app>` or `.build/debug/<my-app>` depending on your compilation mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error in the 'Procfile' file. for example, this is mine:

```
web: Run --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=$PORT
```

Comment: echo web: Run serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below steps to solve your issue.

How to create swift backend API  with the help of Vapor framework. Another framework is also available in the market. But we are choosing swift vapor.

Let’s start.

Install vapor in your system.

Step 1. Run below command to install vapor

```sh
brew install vapor/tap/vapor-beta
```

Check whether vapor installs or not run below command.

```sh
vapor-beta --help
```

These will be useful command of vapor.

Command only when you are in project directory.
You can

```sh
# Created vapor project
vapor new myProjectName

# Build vapor project 
vapor build

# Run vapor project
vapor run 

# You can configure Xcode. You should be inside created project directory. 
vapor Xcode
```

When you have made changes in project file or add new feature for update you have  below command.

```sh
vapor Xcode
```

You can run thru local server test API. Out will be “Hello World”

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/hello
```

===========================================PostgreSQL Setup================================================

Setting Up for local PrortgeSQL. Run below command.

```sh
brew install postgresql
```

Start local database server.  Run below command

```sh
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Stop the local database server. Run below command.

```sh
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

When yow wish to run PostgreSQL as background service with launch you can use brew server. Run below command.

```sh
brew services start postgresql
```

Let start Postgres the by this.

```sh
psql -d postgres
```

Create data base by running below command:

```sh
create databas databaseName
create databas ashi-app # Actual command
```

create user by running below command:- Grant that user the privileges it need with by running below command.

```sh
create user username
create user ashi-app-user # Actual command

grant all privileges on database databaseName to userName
# Actual command
grant all privileges on database ashi-app to ashi-app-user
```

===========================================PostgreSQL Setup================================================

===========================================Deploy fresh app on Heroku================================================

Deploy new swift vapor app on Heroku without database.

Consider you already created Vapor project without database.

Step 1. Navigate on cd MyApp.

```sh
cd myApp
# Actual command
cd ashi-api
```

Step 2. Create swift version file inside your root project directory.Run below on terminal.

```sh
echo 5.1.3 > .swift-version
```

Step 3. Create Procfile file inside your root project directory.Run below on terminal.

```sh
echo web: Run serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT > Procfile
```

Step 4.  Add file git  and commit by below command

```sh
git add .

git commit -m ‘App Setup’
```

Step 5. You should generate linux tests file by below command.

```sh
swift test --generate-linuxmain
```

Step 6.  Add again modified in git by below command.

```sh
git add .

git commit -m ‘Tests setup’
```

Step 7. Login on Heroku. Required to create app on heroku for deployment. So we have login on heruko. By running below command we can login.

```
heroku login
```

Step 8. Once login done create heroku app. Name must we unique most prefer is app-appname.

```sh
heroku apps: create myAppName
heroku apps: create ashi-api # Actual command
```

Step 9.  Add swift build pack with app. For compiling on hereto we have to add buildback. Heroku doesn’t support inbuild pack for swift.

```sh
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack -a myproject

# Actual command
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack -a ashi-api
```

Step 10. Find command push changes on sever.

```sh
git push heroku master
```

Now you app and API will available for testing…

===========================================Deploy fresh app on Heroku================================================

======================Set data base with deployed app and next version of deployment==================================

Step 1. Do database configuration. Replace sqlite database with postgreSQL. Because Heroku is not supporting sqlite.

Replace in App->configure.swift. and import in Todo.h TodoController.h

```swift
import FluentPostgreSQL

// Configure a PostgreSQL database
    let postgreSQLConfig: PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig
    
    if let url = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL") {
      postgreSQLConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(url: url)!
    } else {
      postgreSQLConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", username: "app_test")
    }
    let postgreSQL = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: postgreSQLConfig)

    // Register the configured PostreSQL database to the database config.
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: postgreSQL, as: .psql)
    services.register(databases)
```

Step 2. Install the heroku command with home-brew by running.

```sh
brew tap heroic/brew && brew install heroku
```

Step 3.  We can add postgreSQL in app by running command.

```sh
heroic addons:create heroic-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

Step 4. Add update file in git by running below command.

```sh
git add .

git commit -m ‘Added PostgreSQL file’
```

Step 5. Find command push changes on sever.

```sh
git push heroku master
```

The second version will be available for testing with postgreSQL.

======================Set data base with deployed app and next version of deployment==================================